# Convert Data Frame Start/Stop times into percentage bins

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I want to convert a dataframe of start/end (or on/off) times into a second dataframe with percentages of total 'on time' per some arbitrary time period. In this case, that time period is an hour. I've written a very inefficient solution involving loops, and am looking for a better solution.

```
df1

| Start               | End                 |
|---------------------|---------------------|
| 2020-02-01T00:00:00 | 2020-02-01T02:40:00 |
| 2020-02-01T02:55:00 | 2020-02-01T03:17:00 |
| 2020-02-01T03:27:00 | 2020-02-01T04:12:00 |
| 2020-02-01T04:20:00 | 2020-02-01T04:29:00 |
| 2020-02-01T05:19:00 | 2020-02-01T05:23:00 |
```

```
df2

| Time                | Percent |
|---------------------|---------|
| 2020-02-01T00:00:00 | 1       |
| 2020-02-01T00:01:00 | 1       |
| 2020-02-01T00:02:00 | 0.750   |
| 2020-02-01T00:03:00 | 0.833   |
| 2020-02-01T00:04:00 | 0.350   |
| 2020-02-01T00:05:00 | 0.066   |
```

Comment: `df1['End'].sub(df1['Start'])/pd.to_timedelta('1H')`?

Comment: Thanks Quang, but this only tells me the duration of each start/end pair and doesn't address breaking 'on time' into hour long bins. df2 is expected to have a different number of rows that df1.

Comment: ( 100 * timedelta(hours=1) / (df1.End-df1.Start).resample('1H').sum() )?

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Comment: Thanks jonnor, the two tables (df1 and df2) in the post are part of the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this, if the data is not too big, is to resample on lower frequency and groupby:

```
s = pd.concat([pd.Series(pd.date_range(a,b, freq='S')) 
                  for a,b in zip(df1.Start, df1.End)],
              ignore_index=True
              )
s.groupby(s.dt.floor('H')).count()/3600
```

Output:

```
2020-02-01 00:00:00    1.000000
2020-02-01 01:00:00    1.000000
2020-02-01 02:00:00    0.750278
2020-02-01 03:00:00    0.833611
2020-02-01 04:00:00    0.350556
2020-02-01 05:00:00    0.066944
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Nice approach Quang, however the data is in fact big (measured in years) so storing dataframes with number of rows = seconds is not an approach I can entertain.